# Can HTML font-style Affect Input Length

Tags: html, css

My web page has `input`'s that use `font-style: normal` and `font-style: italic`.

However, looking at my input boxes in Firebug, I see that, upon changing the style of font-style from "normal" to "italic," the width of these italic inputs shortens. As a result, the input's length varies: **shorter** for "font-style: italic" and **longer** for "font-style: normal".

Does this make sense? Or is this likely not the cause?

**EDIT**

After looking at it more, it's clear that the `font-style: italic` input, along with its other style attributes, takes up more space (HTML `size`, I believe) than the `font-style: normal` input.

Comment: I don't see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/g6eLf/ Are you sure that is the only style difference? Some code perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

The (pixel) width of an input, if not explicitly specified, is based on the max text size specified and an avarage width (probably the [en-size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_%28typography%29)). This width can vary based on the font variation, so I can see how it can differ.

Maybe you can solve it by specifying an exact width. If you like relative sizes, you can put the input in a container element. Give that element the width you like in `pt` or `em` units. Give the input 100% of it's parent width (or make it `display: block`).

Now, you can specify a relative width based on the font of the container element, event if the input element has a different font.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What if I set `max-width:Xem` where X = some #? That would limit the width of the input to a defined `em`, right?

Answer (score 2):

The font style can surely affect the width of text. For example, for text in Verdana, text in italic style is wider (in pixels) than the same text in normal style. This is to be expected on the basis of the nature of italic typefaces, but it really depends on font. Consider, for example, normal “l”, which tends to be rather narrow especially in sans-serif fonts, with an “l” in italic, which is more or less slanted and thus requires more width.

It sounds odd (though it is theoretically possible) that italic text is shorter (narrower) than normal text. To analyze a specific situation, some specific code that triggers this behavior is needed, together with information on browser(s) used in testing.